# How do search for multiple email address

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, smtplib

I am logging into gmail via python and deleting emails.  However when I do a search for two emails I get no results to delete.

```
 mail.select('Inbox')
 result,data = mail.uid('search',None '(FROM target.com)')
```

The above works and will find and delete any email that had target.com in the from address.  However when I send in another email address I get nothing.

```
 result,data = mail.uid('search',None '(FROM "target.com" FROM "walmart.com")')
```

Yes I have both target.com and walmart.com emails in my inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail search is exactly like Searching in the gmail website.  If you open that and click the arrow down buttom in the search field you can test things.

[image]

That being said searching on more then one address is not going to work as its going to look for emails that are by both people.  Not all emails containing one or the other.

The following will look for mails that both come from tom and jon. probably not possible as you cant have two senders

```
from:(tom@gmail.com,jon@comcast.net)
```

where as will return all mails that come from gmail.com

```
from:(gmail.com)
```

will only return mails sent from gmail.com and comcast.net which inst possible

```
from:(tom@gmail.com,comcast.net)
```

your going to have to make two requests.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case where it wasn't possible to do the searching with more than one address.

Comment: Googles apis are very singular they would rather you do two requests then fix there api to handle multiples.

Answer (score 1):

You can search set this type of filter:

```
from:(demo@gmail.com OR demo1@yahoo.com)
```